# How to programatically create topic and send message to Kafka using C# dot net client

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-topic

I'm new to kafka and I want to try create topic and send message to kafka from my .net application.
I'm using kafka.net dll and created topic successfully
with this code:

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9092");

        string topic = "testkafka";

        string payload = "test msg";

        var sendMsg = new Thread(() =>

        {

            KafkaNet.Protocol.Message msg = new KafkaNet.Protocol.Message(payload);

            var options = new KafkaOptions(uri);

            var router = new KafkaNet.BrokerRouter(options);

            var client = new Producer(router);

            client.SendMessageAsync(topic, new List<KafkaNet.Protocol.Message> { msg }).Wait();

        });

        sendMsg.Start();
```

but I can't see any message on:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic testkafka --from-beginning
```

anyone can help me with example?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For both actions, you can make use of the [`cofluent-kafka-dotnet`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) client.

---

In order to programatically [create a topic](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/b7b04fed82762c67c2841d7481eae59dee3e4e20/examples/AdminClient/Program.cs):

```
static async Task CreateTopicAsync(string bootstrapServers, string topicName) {

    using (var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(new AdminClientConfig { BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers }).Build()) {
        try {
            await adminClient.CreateTopicsAsync(new TopicSpecification[] { 
                    new TopicSpecification { Name = 'myTopicName', ReplicationFactor = 1, NumPartitions = 1 } });
            } 
            catch (CreateTopicsException e) {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occured creating topic {e.Results[0].Topic}: {e.Results[0].Error.Reason}");
            }
        }
    }
```

---

In order to produce a message:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Confluent.Kafka;

class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ProducerConfig { BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092" };

        // If serializers are not specified, default serializers from
        // `Confluent.Kafka.Serializers` will be automatically used where
        // available. Note: by default strings are encoded as UTF8.
        using (var p = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config).Build())
        {
            try
            {
                var dr = await p.ProduceAsync("myTopicName", new Message<Null, string> { Value="test" });
                Console.WriteLine($"Delivered '{dr.Value}' to '{dr.TopicPartitionOffset}'");
            }
            catch (ProduceException<Null, string> e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Delivery failed: {e.Error.Reason}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Any suggestions without cofluent?

Comment: @maya Why without confluent? It's just a nuget.